# Setting execution policy rights to PowerShell through a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am [setting execution policy rights to PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) through a batch file to allow running of PowerShell scripts.

Windows PowerShell has execution policy as `Restricted` by default. Yes we can start PowerShell with elevated (admin) rights and set policy as `Unrestricted` manually.

Now the question is if we can set it manually then is it makes sense to set it via batch file?

When you need to run your script file on multiple machines (say for testing purpose) it could be a hassle setting policy rights to each machine manually. Although it is not much of a work for a person but this could be an overhead when you ask users to do this setting for themselves. Some users prefer to do as least as possible to make things work.

> So the idea is user just need to execute the batch file with admin
>   rights which will set the policy rights automatically. The path to
>   execute the script should not be a problem because both the batch file
>   and PowerShell script would be in same folder (recommended).

This is what i have tried so far in my batch (.bat) file.

```
powershell.exe -Set ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -FILE file.ps1 "args[0]" "args[1]"....
```

Where `file.ps1` is the name of PowerShell script and `args[0]`, `args[1]`,.... are the optional arguments passed to the script.

The only thing which is not working here is the execution policy. It could be some syntax issue also. Please advise.

Comment: I think you don't have to set up anything. Just start it (WIN key and type 'powershell') and thats it. What exactly you want?

Comment: that is ok,  i know it is a part of operating system and already included in it....i want to perform web UI automation by using this. but it is limited to work on IE browser. can u suggest any other option for doing automation on other browsers..


thanks..

Comment: So you should correct your question. It definitely cannot stay like this.
Take a look at this module - [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution which worked for me.

```
@powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -FILE file.ps1 "args[0]" "args[1]" "args[2]"
```

Eventually, the problem was with the syntax as you can notice.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 comes with Powershell v2.0

Just goto run or start menu and type "Powershell" and hit enter.

To run scripts you might have to do `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` or something similar. Look here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx